# accessing other scope variables inside custom template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display files inside each folder/directory.

I'm using custom directive to disply each of the directories as follows (this part works).

But it fails to resolve the {{file}} variable inside custom template folderListing.html. Can somebody please correct me where I'm going wrong ?

```js
folderListing.js

app.directive('folderListing', function(){
 return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
      listing:'='
     },
     templateUrl: 'js/directives/folderListing.html'
 };
});


RdaController.js
app.controller('RdaController', ['$scope','RdaService', function($scope,RdaService) {
 
    $scope.folders = ['RDA Server Folder','CTP Outbox', 'CTP Inbox', 'CTP Jobs'];
 $scope.sendToCTP = function(file){
  return RdaService.SendFileToCTP(file);
 };
 $scope.listOfFiles = ['learn_javascript.pdf', 'HTML Made Easy.pdf', 'AngularJS for everybody.pdf'];
 
}]);
```

```html
index.html
<folder-listing listing="folder" ng-repeat="folder in folders"></folder-listing>


folderListing.html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3" id="{{listing}}">
<table class="table table-striped">
<h3> {{ listing }} </h3>
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="file in listOfFiles">
   {{file}}
 </div>
</div>
<td><span class="btn-group" role="group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sendToCTP(file)">Execute</button></span></td>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
scope: {
    listing:'='
},
```

You have created an isolate scope passing only `listing` to the directive. You need to change this to:

```
scope: {
    listing: '=',
    listOfFiles: '=',
    sendToCTP: '&sendToCtp'
},
```

To pass the function you'll have to add a `send-to-ctp="sendToCTP(file)"` attribute on your directive. However, in your template your button with `ng-click="sendToCTP(file)"` is outside your `ng-repeat` so `file` will always be undefined.